# What the underlying reason C code will compile using mingw32 in Linux but Visual Studio C has problems

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, mingw

So Im wondering why C code compiled for me with mingw32 (this program here fo reference https://github.com/newsoft/adduser) with no issues or mentions of errors (other than some case-sensitivity in naming of the headers i mean)

Though, when I tried in Visual Studio 2019 I get the following "errors" that need to be cleaned up.

```
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [15]' to 'LPWSTR'   adduser-test2   C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\adduser-test\adduser-test2\adduser-test2.cpp    39  
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [6]' to 'LPWSTR'    adduser-test2   C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\adduser-test\adduser-test2\adduser-test2.cpp    38
```

Is it some sort of strict compiler settings for "safer code"? Or is one compiler actually just able to convert a const wchar_t could convert to a pointer to a wchar_t if necessary

Comment: Isn't it unusual to have C code in files with extension ".cpp"?

Comment: `LPWSTR` is a macro for `wchar_t *`. A constant array like `const wchar_t [15]` will decay to the type `const wchar_t *`. Pointers to constant and non-constant data aren't really compatible. Especially in C++ (as indicated by the `.cpp` suffix) which is very strict about const-correctness.

Comment: `adduser.c` will usually be compiled with a `C` compiler and is legal code in that language. `adduser.cpp` will usually be compiled with a `C++` compiler and is not legal code in that language.  If you rename the file to `adduser.c` MSVS should compile it in `C` mode as it uses the file extension to select the compilation language.

Comment: GCC has a tendency to keep C++ close to C, sometimes extending C++ to make it behave more C-like. Compile the code under g++ with the `-pedantic` flag and you'll get warnings for all of the deviations from the Standard.

Comment: Visual Studio does not support some of C99's features that were subsequently made optional. [Here's a groovy chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160#c-standard-library-features-1)

Comment: @user4581301 _GCC has a tendency to keep C++ close to C_ [Don't think it's that](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ScLfFbkAAxzmKPuK).

Comment: That's a warning rather than the Standard-described hard error, but in this case I believe it's more a case of "Let's not render 30 years of code invalid quite yet."

Comment: @user4581301 Oh yes, so it is.

Comment: If I had to decide which compiler is more correct, I would raise the warning level to the max, compare again, and then I would choose GCC. Microsoft has a tendency to invent its own "standard". If necessary I would try to "adjust" the source so that both compilers are happy.

Comment: When compiled as C++code this time it's Visual Studio that is correct. Non-`const` pointers to `const` C-style strings is forbidden. Some compilers still allow it to make it easier to pass string literals to older or poorly defined interfaces.

Comment: These are great and enlightening discussion points. Thanks all for suggesting possible affects to the curious case. Particularly the .CPP and .C differences. Though, I'll also note that the busybee point is about Microsoft inventing/controlling standards is interesting. As I also once had an old C program that wouldnt compile in VS studio because MSVCRT decided I MUST use safe version of stdlib functions. Good times